# C code compiles as C++, but not as C

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert some code from C++ to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142420/convert-some-code-from-c-to-c)

I've got some code that appears to be straight C. When I tell the compiler (I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Express) to compile it as c++, it compiles and links fine. When I try to compile it as C, though, it throws this error:

```
1>InpoutTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Out32@8 referenced in function _main
1>InpoutTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Inp32@4 referenced in function _main
```

The code reads from and writes to the parallel port, using Inpout.dll. I have both Inpout.lib and Inpout.dll. Here's the code:

```
// InpoutTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
/* ----Prototypes of Inp and Outp--- */

short _stdcall Inp32(short PortAddress);
void _stdcall Out32(short PortAddress, short data);

/*--------------------------------*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

 int data;

 if(argc<3)
 {
  //too few command line arguments, show usage
  printf("Error : too few arguments\n\n***** Usage *****\n\nInpoutTest read <ADDRESS> \nor \nInpoutTest write <ADDRESS> <DATA>\n\n\n\n\n");
 } 
 else if(!strcmp(argv[1],"read"))
 {

  data = Inp32(atoi(argv[2]));

  printf("Data read from address %s is %d \n\n\n\n",argv[2],data);

 }
 else if(!strcmp(argv[1],"write"))
 {
  if(argc<4)
  {
   printf("Error in arguments supplied");
   printf("\n***** Usage *****\n\nInpoutTest read <ADDRESS> \nor \nInpoutTest write <ADDRESS> <DATA>\n\n\n\n\n");
  }
  else
  {
  Out32(atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3]));
  printf("data written to %s\n\n\n",argv[2]);
  }
 }



 return 0;
}
```

I previously asked this question, incorrectly, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142420/convert-some-code-from-c-to-c).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does C use mangled names these days? I'm looking at the `@4` and `@8` in the linker errors. Doesn't look like C++ name mangling, unless I'm seriously confused, but those certainly aren't undecorated function names.

Comment: This is just a minor rewording of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142420/convert-some-code-from-c-to-c. Try not to double post.

Comment: @Evan: I re-asked because I wasn't getting new input to the other question. Sorry.

Comment: @Steve Visual Studio mangles _stdcall C functions as _name@number-of-bytes-passed-as-arguments; `Inp32` has 4 bytes of arguments, while `Out32` has 8. ( [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows) )

Comment: You might also want to make sure you're using the right calling convention when mixing C/C++. C compilers generally use "cdecl" as opposed to "stdcall" for C++ compilers (this is per function).

Comment: We have here a dupe ping-pong (orig is closed as the dupe of this), I suggest a reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to link to a C++ function, from C. That doesn't work due to name mangling- the linker doesn't know where to look for your function. If you want to call a C function from C++, you must mark it extern "C". C does not support extern "C++"- as far as I know. One of the other answers says there is. Alternatively, recompile it's source code as C.

Edit: Why ever would you compile as C if you could compile as C++, anyway?

Comment: I need to make the calls to Out32 from a C project which throws a bunch of errors if I try to compile as C++.

Comment: I recompiled the source for the lib as C, and it worked. (After I changed a reference from afxres.h to winres.h)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like `Inp32` and `Out32` are defined externally in a C++ file/library, so you need to mark them as such so the compiler knows how their names will be mangled:

```
extern "C++" {
    short _stdcall Inp32(short PortAddress);
    void _stdcall Out32(short PortAddress, short data);
}
```

Comment: That gives error C2059: syntax error : 'string'

Comment: Is there an `extern "C++"`? Could it be non-portable? I'd use `extern "C"`, in the header file where those functions are decared, with `#ifdef` guards so that only C++ compilers see it. C compilers already use C call conventions.

Comment: @Steve There is, although it is much more common to do it the other way; I'm not sure about portability, as I've never actually needed to use it. If it's a library he doesn't control/have source for he doesn't have much choice though

Comment: `extern C++` is portable C++, but it can't be used when compiling a C translation unit (since it's not C), so it's not appropriate in this particular situation. `extern "C++"` is only rarely useful - there are some C++ constructs that cannot be inside an `extern "C"` block, but you generally don't need to put them there anyway. See Microsoft's winnt.h for an example use of `extern "C++"`.

Comment: @Michael - If he doesn't have the source, surely the thing to do is to write a small adapter library? Have C-linkage functions compiled in C++ that call the provided C++ functions.

Comment: @Steve314 - you read my mind (see my overly-long answer).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to call a C++ routine from C code, then the C++ routine need to have "C" linkage, which is done by marking the function as `extern "C"`.  That needs to be done on the C++ side.

Put the following as the prototypes for `Inp32()` and `Outp32()` if you're able to  change the existing C++ code.  This should be in a header that's included by whatever calls or defined the `Inp32()` or `Outp32()` functions - whether C or C++ code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

short _stdcall Inp32(short PortAddress);
void _stdcall Out32(short PortAddress, short data);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

That will mark those functions as having a C calling convention, and those functions will be callable by either C or C++ code.

If you don't have the ability to change the C++ code, you can create your own C-compatible wrappers for the C++ functions in your own C++ module:

The wrappers.h header file:

```
// in wrappers.h

// C-callable wrappers

#ifndef WRAPPERS_H
#define WRAPPERS_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

short Inp32_wrapper( short PortAddress);
void Out32_wrapper( short PortAddress, short data);    

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* WRAPPERS_H */
```

And, the wrappers.cpp implementation:

```
// in wrappers.cpp file:

#include "wrappers.h"

// prototypes for the C++ functions - these really should be in a
//  header file...

short _stdcall Inp32(short PortAddress);
void _stdcall Out32(short PortAddress, short data);

// implementation of the wrappers

short Inp32_wrapper( short PortAddress)
{
    return Inp32( PortAddress);
}

void Out32_wrapper( short PortAddress, short data)
{
    Out32( PortAddress, data);
}
```

Now your C code can `#include "wrappers.h"` and call the wrapper functions which will simply call the existing C++ functions to do the work.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to be a compiler error, but rather a linker error. The linker can't find the definitions of `Inp32` and `Out32`. Are you linking to the library that contains the definitions? Did you spell them correctly?

Comment: The only thing I did was change the settings of the files to compile as C rather than C++. I didn't change any linking or anything. Is there something I need to change in the linker settings?